# friendly_id gem with rails, converting to SEO friendly urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, seo, friendly-id

I'm using friendly_id and rails 3.2.   I'm trying to convert a products table to have clean urls.   I'm having no issues using the new slug column,  and urls are generating fine like

example.com/products/new-friendly-url

The problem I am running into, is I still want to keep the unique id from active record, or some other unique identifier.   The reason being, is that many product might have the same friendly title.  If I have a product that has the exact same title,  the current behavior is generating a slug with some unique identify already such as:

example.com/products/new-friendly-url--2

So friendly_id is generating unique slugs, but I'm just trying to change the format and not sure where/how to do that.

Is there a way to remove the extra --, and just have one "-" that friendly_id is adding?

Here is my model

```
       class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
       extend FriendlyId
       friendly_id :title, :use => :slugged

       attr_accessible :description, :image, :posted_by, :title, :url,       
       :price

       validates_format_of :price, :with => /^[0-9]+$/

       belongs_to :user
       has_many :comments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the sequence seperator in configurations of friendly-id.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title do |config|
    config.use :slugged
    config.sequence_separator = ":"  
  end 
end
```

The action that changes the seperator to '-' is not suggested. The document says:

> The string used to separate a slug base from a numeric sequence.
>
> By default, -- is used to separate the slug from the sequence.
>   FriendlyId uses two dashes to distinguish sequences from slugs with
>   numbers in their name.
>
> You can change the default separator by setting the sequence_separator
>   configuration option.
>
> For obvious reasons, you should avoid setting it to “-” unless you're
>   sure you will never want to have a friendly id with a number in it.

http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/4.0/FriendlyId/Slugged/Configuration.html#sequence_separator-instance_method

If you can use Rails 4, you can upgrade friendly-id to 5.0, it solves this automatically.